# Custom actions and redirecting properly after success on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller

I'm actually working on a small app, where a user can create an event. It has to be done in three steps.
To achieve this, I created two custom actions in the related controller. Each view has a form using the `update` url.
Then I customized the update method this way:

```
    def training
      @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
      @coach = Coach.find(@event.coach_id)
    end

    def confirm
      @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    end

    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @event.update(event_params)
          if params[:commit] == 'next'
            format.html { redirect_to booking_event_confirm_path(@event), notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
          else
            format.html { redirect_to booking_event_path(@event), notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
          end
        else
          if params[:commit] == 'next
            format.html { render :training }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

As a Rails beginner, I would be happy to get some feedback... Does this seems ok, or would it be a better way to achieve my goal?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not bad, but there is a better way to achieve it. I would suggest you checking [Wicked gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) and [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@nicolasblanco/developing-a-wizard-or-multi-steps-forms-in-rails-d2f3b7c692ce).

In general, google a wizard or multi-step form.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Btw, I'm adding validations and noticed that on error, the `render :training` has strange behaviour: display is ok, but the url is changed from `booking/events/:id/training` to `booking/events/:id`... Any idea ? Thx again